# How to close wpdb connection?

Tags: database, wpdb

Is there any method to close connection similar to `mysql_close()` for `wpdb` in WordPress?
Is it not necessary to close connection for global `wpdb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WP 4.5 had introduced `wpdb->close()` method to close connection in current instance.

---

Old answer

<del>There is no explicit method. It stores link identifier in `$wpdb->dbh` field, but it is protected, so not convenient to run close on.</del>

Comment: means it is not needed to close global wpdb connection????

Comment: @Brij unless I am missing something it should be closed automatically when page finishes loading and PHP ends execution.

Comment: "This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0."

Comment: @jgraup cheers, updated answer with info about new method which handles that.

Comment: Is it necessary to close connection for global wpdb?

Comment: @Rarst Is it necessary to close the connection for each global wpdb which uses on a theme of a plugin?

Comment: @D.JCode if you are reusing global `$wpdb` you definitely shouldn't close it, it's just a single connection for everything and not a problem. You would only want to explicitly close if you are creating a lot of new wpdb instances (not something I ever seen done in WP).